# Unable to resolve path to module 'recharts/types/util/types'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

I am trying to import this recharts v2.8 type via

```
import { StackOffsetType } from 'recharts/types/util/types';
```

However, I get the error `Unable to resolve path to module 'recharts/types/util/types'` even though  I can open this file in node modules. Is there a way around this?

It seems like recharts only exports one type:
https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/src/index.ts#L107

My only thought is to create the type in our project.